# How do I make the circuit to sense the collector current for the FAN1100-F085?

Tags: coil, igbt, current-sensing

I am *trying* to design an ignition coil driver using the [FAN1100-F085](https://www.onsemi.jp/download/data-sheet/pdf/fan1100_f085-d.pdf) IC and a [ISL9V3040x3ST−F085C](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/isl9v3040-f085c-d.pdf) IGBT.

I am having trouble understanding the datasheet when it comes to the current sensing. It says to use a 20 mΩ resistor, but that seems quite small and it not very common.

I followed the typical application schematic to create this schematic with values I think are correct:

[image]

How would I create the current sensing part, on a breadboard for testing if even possible, or a pcb? Do I have to use a resistor or can the 20 mΩ be achieved with some kind of trace pattern?

Comment: You should be able to find a 4-terminal 20 mOhm current sense resistor fairly easily from Digi-Key or other distributors.  This type of circuit shouldn't be breadboarded, you should do a PCB layout.

Comment: _”20 mΩ resistor, but that seems quite small and it not very common”_ There are 227 different 20 mohm resistors in stock to choose from at DigiKey at the moment. Link: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/chip-resistor-surface-mount/52?s=N4IgjCBcoEwAwA4CsVQGMoBcBOBXApgDQgD2UA2iPAAQC2A8gBa0DOIAusQA6ZQgCqAOwCWmegDMAsvgCGLXNnwgAvsQC0MVCAyQcBYmUiUU7ZWaA

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked the distributors instead of google. Why a 4 terminal resistor? How can I calculate what wattage it should be?

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be a 4-terminal resistor if you're careful about the layout, but if you want best performance it's recommended.  See here: https://www.bourns.com/docs/technical-documents/technical-library/current-sense-pulse-power-high-power-resistors/application-notes/bourns_n1702_current_sense_accurate_measurement_appnote.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this should get me on my way

Comment: What @JohnD said. There are edge cases where you really need a four terminal shunt resistor but the vast majority of use cases will do fine with a two terminal resistor and a four terminal footprint. The latter comes for free.